# SF story about children from different parts of the galaxy telling stories from their homeworlds

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I am trying to find a book I read before 2017.

I remember it was about a group of children from all parts of our galaxy gathering through holograms and telling stories from their homeworlds. I think it was what they did during vacation. I remember one girl was from Alpha Centauri.

I think the book had (few) illustrations in black and white.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Was this a cartoon, live action TV show, book, comic book, something else? What year did you read or watch it? What language was it written in?

Comment: Hi it was before 2017 at least and it was a book but I think there might have been one or two illustrations

Comment: I think there was illustrations in black and white too